# htaccess and regex - handling domain in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Imagine in my website I want to show some analytic about domains, working URL example of what I need:

`http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com`

As you see in the above URL, it's handling `google.com` as a variable and pass it to another page to process the given variable, that's exactly what I want.

So for detecting that kind of variable, here is my regex:

`/^[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-?[a-zA-Z\d])+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/`

The above RegEx is simple and accepts everything like: `google.com`, so in my `.htaccess` file I have:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-?[a-zA-Z\d])+\.[a-zA-Z]+$ modules/pages/page.php?domain=$1
```

the above rule does the trick to redirect every domains to `page.php`, but it's not passing the `domain` as a variable... . I tried to put `(.*)$` at the end somewhere, but it's not working... .

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your rewrite rule to :

```
RewriteRule (^[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:-?[a-zA-Z\d])+\.[a-zA-Z]+$) modules/pages/page.php?domain=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: in php side I'm doing  `echo $_GET['domain']`, it echos `page.php` which is wrong...

Comment: found the problem, it needs to start with `(^[a-zA-Z\d]`, notice the `^` after the parentheses, now it's working, edit your answer so I can accept it